# Why I can't store/retrieve 11 digit long number properly

Tags: c, numbers, long-integer

I'm creating a C program as my last project for this year in my school and they wanted to let me create a student database program. Here it is, works almost flawless but it won't register the ID numbers properly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht4Y8.png

On this image you can clearly see I've entered 23915741843 as the ID number but it registered itself as; -1854061933.

I've used long to fix it, but nope. It won't really work. I'm allowed to take help from the internet. So here is my full code. What's wrong with it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct
{
    long int id;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
}student;

int main()
{
   long int idnumber;
   int flag,choice,shift,found,continu,length;
   char studentname[20];
   FILE *fp;

    printf("\n\tC PROGRAM OF STUDENT DATABASE SYSTEM"); 
   Label1:
      printf("\n1 -> Store a new record in database\n");
      printf("2 -> Search a student record by Student First Name\n");
      printf("3 -> Search a student record by ID\n");
      printf("4 -> Quit Student Database");
      printf("\n\n");
      printf("Enter your choice : ");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
      switch(choice)
      {
       case  1:
       Label2:
       printf("\nEnter Student Details:\n\nID number: ");
       scanf("%d",&student.id);
       printf("\nName:");
       scanf("%s",student.firstname);
       printf("\nSurname:");
       scanf("%s",student.lastname);
       printf("\nMark(0 - 100 integer) : ");
       scanf("%d",&student.mark);
       fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","a+");
       fprintf(fp,"\n%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t",student.id,student.firstname,student.lastname,student.mark);
       fclose(fp);
       printf("A student record has been added successfully...\n");
       printf("\n\n1 -> Wish to add another record to database");
       printf("\n2 -> Wish to move to Main Menu");
       printf("\n3 -> Exit from Program\n");
       scanf("%d",&shift);
       if(shift==1)
        goto Label2;
       if(shift==2)
        goto Label1;
       if(shift==3)
        break;
       if(shift!=1&&2&&3){
        printf("Exiting.........");
        break;
        }

       case 2:
       Label4:
       printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
       scanf("%s",&studentname);
       printf("Searching record with studentname=%s.\n",studentname);
           found=0;
           if((fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","r"))==NULL)
        {
            printf(" ! The File is Empty...\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(!feof(fp)&& found==0)
                {
                fscanf(fp,"\n%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t",&student.id,student.firstname,student.lastname,&student.mark);
                length = strlen(student.firstname);
                if(student.firstname[length]==studentname[length])
                    found=1;
            }
            }
       if(found)
       {
         printf("\nThe record is found.\n");
         printf("\nID: %d\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",student.id,student.firstname,student.lastname,student.mark);
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Not found...\n");
         getch();
       }
       Label5:
       printf("\n\n1 -> Wish to search another record");
       printf("\n2 -> Wish to move to Main Menu");
       printf("\n3 -> Exit from Program\n");
       scanf("%d",&shift);
       if(shift==1)
        goto Label4;
       if(shift==2)
        goto Label1;
       if(shift==3)
        break;
       if(shift!=1&&2&&3){
        printf("\nEnter a valid choice");
        goto Label5;
        }
       case 3: 
       Label6:
       printf("\nEnter the ID: ");
       scanf("%d",&idnumber);
       printf("Searching record with ID=%d.\n",idnumber);
           found=0;
           if((fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","r"))==NULL)
        {
            printf(" ! The File is Empty...\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(!feof(fp)&& found==0)
                {
                fscanf(fp,"\n%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t",&student.id,student.firstname,student.lastname,&student.mark);
                if(student.id==idnumber)
                    found=1;
            }
            }
       if(found)
       {
         printf("\nThe record is found.");
         printf("\nID no: %d\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",student.id,student.firstname,student.lastname,student.mark);
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Not found...\n");
         getch();
       }
       Label7:
       printf("\n\n1 -> Wish to search more..");
       printf("\n2 -> Wish to move to Main Menu");
       printf("\n3 -> Exit from Program\n");
       scanf("%d",&shift);
       if(shift==1)
        goto Label6;
       if(shift==2)
        goto Label1;
       if(shift==3)
        break;
       if(shift!=1&&2&&3){
        printf("\nEnter a valid choice");
        goto Label7;
        }
       case 4: break;
       default :
          printf(" Bad choice...Enter the choice again...\n");
          goto Label1;
        }

      getch();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: can't you use functions? don't use `goto` for that. `goto` is useful, but not in this situations. If you are not allowed to use functions then it's ok.

Comment: A "student ID number" is actually *a string that happens to contain digits*, not a *number* (you don't do maths with it). You might want to handle it as a string. That would help in some cases (e.g. a leading `0` in the student ID, allowing punctuation or whitespace between the digits...). *Edit*: also, consider what will happen if someone enters more than 19 characters as the name.

Comment: @DCoder that's right, let me try to turn it into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR --> Please use appropriate format specifiers and always check for the limit of the value that can be held by the used data type.

In your code,

```
scanf("%d",&student.id);
```

`%d` is not the correct format specifier for `long int`.

- For `long int` it should be `%ld`
- For `unsigned long int` it should be `%lu`

Also, `23915741843` is a value too big to be held by `long int`.  From `§5.2.4.2.1` of `c99`

> maximum value for an object of type long int
>
> LONG_MAX  +2147483647 // 2<sup>31</sup> - 1

You may use `long long int` [`%lld`].

Sidenote: You never checked for the success of `fopen()`, `scanf()` etc.

Comment: I made it long long int and changed `scanf("%d",&student.id);` part with `scanf("%lld",&student.id);` now;

Unhandled exception at 0x60e5984f error appeared. (While registering.)

Comment: I'm only changed the code as you wanted.

long long int's on 7th and 15th line.
scanf change on 34th line.

Program compiled but whenever I tried to register a test student. It gave this error.

Comment: @tommythelittleguy did you check _all_ the format specifiers?

Comment: I've changed all the %d's through %lld which are related with student.id but now if I try to launch the program it says, Unable to start the program. OLE sent a request and awaiting for a response.

Comment: @tommythelittleguy i'm not very sure about this particular error message. also I don't think this is related to your code. However, check the sidenote in my updated answer.

Comment: @tommythelittleguy well, I can't see the link as i'm on restricted network. Hope your code worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%ld",&student.id);
```

Use proper format specifier to scan long int. IMO `id` will be an unsigned value so if that is a mistake make `id` as `unsinged long int id` and use `%lu` to scan the value . Please make sure that the value fits the allowed range if not then use `long long int` and scan it accordingly using `%lld` format specifier.

Your code looks obfuscate with using `goto` make sure you overcome it.

Display your prompt and have switch cases handling it accordingly. If the user wants to exit have a seperate case for it and handle this case instead of using `goto`